# Rails: App Templates / script generators with HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Is there any way to create an app template in Rails that generates the views in HAML rather than ERB?

App Templates: http://railscasts.com/episodes/148-app-templates-in-rails-2-3

If not, are there any plugins/gems that I can use to have all my generator scripts output HAML instead of ERB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [norman's haml-scaffold on Github](http://github.com/norman/haml-scaffold).

Answer (score 12):

My favorite: http://github.com/indirect/haml-rails

Answer (score 1):

Another one by Mister Bleigh http://github.com/mbleigh/haml-rails

Answer (score 0):

if you download ryanb's nifty_generators and look at the source code, you can see that he has the following in one of his files

```
  if options[:haml]
    m.directory 'public/stylesheets/sass'
    m.template "layout.html.haml", "app/views/layouts/#{file_name}.html.haml"
    m.file     "stylesheet.sass",  "public/stylesheets/sass/#{file_name}.sass"
  else
    m.template "layout.html.erb", "app/views/layouts/#{file_name}.html.erb"
    m.file     "stylesheet.css",  "public/stylesheets/#{file_name}.css"
  end
```

This allows the user to do script/generate nifty_layout --haml

goo luck